# TwitterKit Parse error. Expected ')' and Expected a type

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, cocoapods

I use Fabric 1.6.7 & TwitterKit 1.15.3 with CocoaPods. However, I keep have problem about Expected ')' and Expected a type. Can any one help me figure out what's the problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get rid of this problem. Just uninstalled the TwitterKit completely and then reinstall it. I think CocoaPods might forget to update some legacy code somewhere so that simply updating the TwitterKit doesn't work.

Comment: I was using the fabric app. I uninstalled everything and then COULDN'T reinstall because Fabric was convinced everything was running fine... idiots. I'll have to use cocoapods instead.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your file import UIKit Or Add UIkit import in Project .pch file globally.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Then check if it solve your error.

Comment: The errors appear in the files in the Pods directory. I don't think I should modify those files.